# Soft-gluon of scattering amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, quantum-chromodynamics, scattering-cross-section

The question from *Scattering Amplitudes in Gauge Theory and Gravity* page 46, equation (2.120) from which I can't get a consistent formula.

I just calculate A3(gff) which two fermion and one gluon $A_n\left[\ldots,f^+_{i-1},i^−,f^-_{i+1},\ldots\right]$
sign show helicity of particle.

Use Feynman diagram of qed soft-photo from Peskin page 182 equation (6.20).
[image: 1]

I get formula of the first term of (2.120) as
$$-\frac{\langle i+1,i \rangle[q,i-1]}{[qi] s_{i,i+1}}$$
instead of the one shown below.
[image: 2]

Which is the correct formula?

Comment: Elvang anf Huang's metric convention is mostly positive, P$\&$S is mostly negative. Have you taken care of this?